# Thoughts on storing ID's (such as Ticket ID, Case ID) in HTML

Tags: javascript, security

This is sort of a generic "Good Idea/Bad Idea question".

**My scenario:** I am writing an ASP.NET MVC3 app that is just 1 page (one View/Controller).  This view shows a grid of "**Cases**" and when a user clicks one of these **Cases**, I use jquery ajax (`$.ajax`) to swap out the visible portion of the page and load the details of this **Case** (but never change the page).

Still with me?  Thanks!

Now, once this new **Case** detail view is shown, the user can edit the **Case** in one of many ways.  Change the priority, change the status, etc.  I am using jquery's ajax function for this as well.

**My question**: *How should I store the Case ID?  Is it ok to store it in the HTML?  Is there a better place to store it?*

All of the **Cases** have a Guid ID, and currently when the **Case** details are loaded (using ajax) I add a custom attribute to the **Case** detail view `<div>` so I know the **Case** ID.  This means that the **Case** ID is visible to anybody viewing the page source.  I thought about using jQuery's .data() function to store it, which wouldn't be visible to page source, but would be accessible from Firebug other inspector tools.

What is the best practice for this?  I really can't imagine how my user's would do anything with the **Case** ID, but I am trying to be a bit paranoid here.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts!  And thanks for reading this novel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's very little you can do about things which the browser gets to see in any fashion, since code and data in the DOM are not protected from the user.

Obviously you don't want to send anything to a user who is not allowed to see that information - so you don't want to do any client-side filtering of data that is dependent upon user role.

But as for internal data, you just have to protect your perimeter - methods can't accept ids which are mismatched (i.e. an account id which is only valid for a different customer being submitted) - but there's very little you can do about the ids themselves.

Comment: Thanks Case.  I sort of figured that there is no "magic" way to get these Id's without exposing them to the user, but I wanted to throw it out here to see what other smart programmers have come up with.  I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1):

By sending the case ID from the server to the browser, you are giving it to the user.  If you don't want the user to have the case ID, don't send it to the browser.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  I appreciate the input.  What would be a good method to know which case is being updated?  Maybe some other made up ID?  Since I never change the page, I can't really do it in the controller.  I need the JavaScript to tell my controller which Case to change the Priority/Status for.

Answer (score 1):

I'd provide some sort of sanitized, "imaginary" ID if you're that concerned. If this were running in a loop, I'd suggest basing it on the loop index.

Ultimately however, you'll need to use some sort of unique identifier on the Case that will identify it in ajax calls to the database.

Really though, I've done the same thing before and just encoded the ID field in the markup, and it's rarely mattered. This ID is only a harmful thing to have out in the open if your security is lax. If you've secured your database and have a decent level of security on the app, then you should be fine. If you haven't, then you have bigger things to worry about than markup.